# Filter query in Meta table Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

users Tabel

```
**id|name**

   1|xx
```

users_meta Table

```
id | user_id | metaKey | metavalue

  1 | 1        | city     | kolkata

  2 |2         |city      | london

  3 |8         |city      |london
```

My moto is to return users belongs to city London.How can i achive this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query using `whereHas`:

```
User::whereHas('users_meta', function ($query) {
    $query->where('metavalue', 'london');
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say u have a relationship with Users and user_meta

Than simply

```
User::with(['userMeta' => function($query){
  $query->where('metaKey', 'city')
  $query->where('metavalue', 'london')
}]);
```

Hope this helps